# GGplot boxplot and dotplot side by side

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphics, boxplot

I'm using R and GGplot2 and I want to make a graph in which there are boxes (from `geom_boxplot`) and points (from `geom_dotplot`) one next to the other, not above one another.
The picture shows what I've managed to do for now, which is pretty much what I'd like to have except that, instead of the pink boxes, I want just the points from the `geom_dotplot`

[image]

```
df2%>%ggplot(aes(factor(Organ), value,fill=Crop)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  #geom_dotplot(binaxis='y',stackdir = 'center')
  scale_y_log10("BCF") + facet_wrap(~Csoil)+theme(axis.title.x=element_blank())
```

This is a subset of the data that I'm using:

```
df2=structure(list(variable = structure(c(8L, 2L, 6L, 14L, 5L, 14L, 
3L, 8L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 13L, 5L, 7L, 13L, 3L, 8L, 10L, 10L, 2L, 2L, 
8L, 6L, 9L, 10L, 14L, 14L, 1L, 4L, 13L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Label = c("BCF leaf (CsoilMax) - Ryegrass", 
"BCF root (CsoilMax) - Ryegrass", "BCF root (CsoilMed) - Ryegrass", 
"BCF stem (CsoilMax) - Ryegrass", "BCF stem (CsoilMed) - Ryegrass", 
"BCF leaf (CsoilMed) - Ryegrass", "BCF fruit (CsoilMax) - Maize", 
"BCF fruit (CsoilMed) - Maize", "BCF leaf (CsoilMax) - Maize", 
"BCF leaf (CsoilMed) - Maize", "BCF root (CsoilMax) - Maize", 
"BCF root (CsoilMed) - Maize", "BCF stem (CsoilMax) - Maize", 
"BCF stem (CsoilMed) - Maize"), class = "factor"), value = c(0.209606259766772, 
0.506401960143269, 0.000660265316109507, 6.51930210129075, 0.0207635735841085, 
0.765736181143394, 1.40601301731962, 0.00743553520916094, 0.040587560806454, 
1.60441689044071, 0.522063333823462, 0.540632385379595, 0.0497467701708571, 
0.0573435549206478, 0.0109218792177719, 0.608263306408034, 0.911628697794879, 
0.0874473327218576, 0.105726788757446, 0.267232334133824, 1.3297503892306, 
0.292440363142525, 0.037969380254565, 0.000157551659778798, 0.237462116816578, 
0.0447547790805731, 1.29271738284098, 0.000673871813931306, 0.00388673588576815, 
0.0223297222656565, 6.82, 11.53, 5.39, 5, 5, 0.005, 107.984, 
26.987, 0.005, 0.005, 132.28), Crop = c("Maize", "Ryegrass", 
"Ryegrass", "Maize", "Ryegrass", "Maize", "Ryegrass", "Maize", 
"Ryegrass", "Ryegrass", "Ryegrass", "Maize", "Ryegrass", "Maize", 
"Maize", "Ryegrass", "Maize", "Maize", "Maize", "Ryegrass", "Ryegrass", 
"Maize", "Ryegrass", "Maize", "Maize", "Maize", "Maize", "Ryegrass", 
"Ryegrass", "Maize", "Literature", "Literature", "Literature", 
"Literature", "Literature", "Literature", "Literature", "Literature", 
"Literature", "Literature", "Literature"), Csoil = c("Median soil C", 
"Maximum soil C", "Median soil C", "Median soil C", "Median soil C", 
"Median soil C", "Median soil C", "Median soil C", "Median soil C", 
"Median soil C", "Maximum soil C", "Maximum soil C", "Median soil C", 
"Maximum soil C", "Maximum soil C", "Median soil C", "Median soil C", 
"Median soil C", "Median soil C", "Maximum soil C", "Maximum soil C", 
"Median soil C", "Median soil C", "Maximum soil C", "Median soil C", 
"Median soil C", "Median soil C", "Maximum soil C", "Maximum soil C", 
"Maximum soil C", "Median soil C", "Median soil C", "Median soil C", 
"Median soil C", "Median soil C", "Median soil C", "Median soil C", 
"Median soil C", "Median soil C", "Median soil C", "Median soil C"
), Organ = c("Fruits", "Roots", "Leaves", "Stem", "Stem", "Stem", 
"Roots", "Fruits", "Stem", "Leaves", "Roots", "Stem", "Stem", 
"Fruits", "Stem", "Roots", "Fruits", "Leaves", "Leaves", "Roots", 
"Roots", "Fruits", "Leaves", "Leaves", "Leaves", "Stem", "Stem", 
"Leaves", "Stem", "Stem", "Leaves lit.", "Leaves lit.", "Roots lit.", 
"Roots lit.", "Roots lit.", "Fruits lit.", "Fruits lit.", "Fruits lit.", 
"Fruits lit.", "Fruits lit.", "Fruits lit.")), .Names = c("variable", 
"value", "Crop", "Csoil", "Organ"), row.names = c(NA, -41L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was just filtering the data within ggplot.
This is the code of the graph:

```
df2%>%ggplot(aes(factor(Organ), value,fill=Crop)) + 
  geom_boxplot(data=.%>%filter(Crop!="Literature")) + 
  geom_dotplot(data=.%>%filter(Crop=="Literature"),binaxis='y',stackdir = 'center',dotsize=0.35,fill="black") +
  scale_y_log10("BCF") + facet_wrap(~Csoil)+theme(axis.title.x=element_blank())
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a real answer but a suggestion: I tend to prefer `geom_jitter(size = 0.5, width = 0.2)` to overlay dots with boxplots, and use the `outlier.size = NULL` argument in `geom_boxplot` not to duplicate dots.